# colorbox onError

Tags: colorbox

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

I am using color box.

```
$('#.boxItems').colorbox({onComplete:function(){

alert("completed");

}});
```

onComplete  work  when the  event is completed.

But at some particular cases im my application onComplete don't work
I know it is because some error happening at my server side

BUT ,can i have a call back function onError()

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery selector you are using is odd. Consider changing to be one of the following (not both like you have it):

- `$('.boxItems').colorbox`...
- `$('#boxItems').colorbox`...

As far as I know, ColorBox doesn't support an onError callback.  Set a breakpoint inside the ColorBox script to trap your action.